# Need LOG4J to drop .log from our file name when appending .date extension

Tags: log4j

Hello we have applications that write to a file called xfiles.log. Log4j does a daily rename to xfiles.log.date, for example xfiles.log.2009-04-12. I would like to remove the '.log' and just have a date extension. For example the new file would be xfiles.2009-04-12. Below is our current log4j setup. Thanks

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, DAILY
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN

log4j.appender.DAILY=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DAILY.file=${LOGDIR}/xfiles.log
log4j.appender.DAILY.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.DAILY.append=true
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c %m %n
```

Comment: hi, what about deleting the `.log` part from setup?

Comment: Not a bad idea. The ops team liked the .log on the files they just want the .log dropped from the file when it rolls.